# Remove content from string if it starts and ends with a certain string

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hello I am having a bit of trouble with this regex

I want to remove all content that starts and ends with the following

Starts with: `<!--`

Ends with: `-->`

Example of string to be removed:

```
<!-- <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="/web/20120124023607/http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
            xmlns:dc="/web/20120124023607/http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:trackback="/web/20120124023607/http://madskills.com/public/xml/rss/module/trackback/">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="/web/20120124023607/http://www.flatfeets.com/flat-feet-foot-definition/"
    dc:identifier="/web/20120124023607/http://www.flatfeets.com/flat-feet-foot-definition/"
    dc:title="What Is Flat Feet Or Flat Foot ?"
    trackback:ping="/web/20120124023607/http://www.flatfeets.com/flat-feet-foot-definition/trackback/" />
 -->
```

My code that is not working:

```
 Function StripGarbage(ByVal article As String) As String
        Return Regex.Replace(article, "<!--(.+?)-->", "")
    End Function
```

Comment: Try using `[\S\s]` instead of `.`

Comment: Did you mean to say ends with `-->` rather than `<!--`?

Comment: Yes I did actually, my mistake.

Comment: vihan's solution works perfectly.

Comment: @vihan: Can you please explain why the dot does not work but `[\S\s]` does? The OP's regex seems to be ok.

Comment: @ZachJohnson I've added my answer which explains this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[\S\s]` instead of `.`, it'll allow the Regular Expression to match across multiple lines